# Access the underlying UIKit view from a SwiftUI View Modifier

Tags: swiftui, uikit, viewmodifier

Is there a way to work with UIKit within the context of a SwiftUI ViewModifier?

I would like to drop to UIKit here:

```swift
struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        // Work on `content` using UIKit here.
        // E.g. I would like to add a subview or CALayer to the existing `content` view
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not. Just interface with one of the Representables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a `UIView` to your SwiftUI view hierarchy, wrap it in a [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable#). You can learn more in the WWDC 2019 session [*Integrating SwiftUI*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/?time=488) starting at 8m08s.

If you want to add a `CALayer`, you'll need to add it as a sublayer of a `UIView`'s layer, and host that `UIView` using `UIViewRepresentable`.

Based on your question title, “Access the underlying UIKit view from a SwiftUI View Modifier”, I wonder if you think each SwiftUI view has a corresponding `UIView`. It doesn't. SwiftUI can use a single (private, custom) `UIView` to draw many SwiftUI views. Let's take a look.

Here's a `UIViewRepresentable` that wraps a custom `UIView` subclass. The subclass does just one custom thing: it prints the UIKit view hierarchy when it's moved to a window.

```
struct UIKitPeeker: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyView {
        return MyView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MyView, context: Context) { }

    class MyView: UIView {
        var callback: (UIView) -> () = { _ in }

        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            super.didMoveToWindow()

            // The recursiveDescription method is only for debugging.
            // Don't use it in App Store submissions!
            print(window?.value(forKey: "recursiveDescription") as? String ?? "nil")
        }
    }
}
```

I'll use it like this:

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            Text("world")
            Color.pink.frame(width: 10, height: 10)
            Toggle("toggle", isOn: .constant(false))
            Text("lots of SwiftUI views here")
        }
        .background { UIKitPeeker() }
    }
}
```

Here's the output (using Xcode 15.0 beta 2):

```
<UIWindow: 0x10570c230; frame = (0 0; 393 852); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c20510>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x600000c02310>>
   | <UITransitionView: 0x105710b20; frame = (0 0; 393 852); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000025b400>>
   |    | <UIDropShadowView: 0x1057115c0; frame = (0 0; 393 852); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000025b8c0>>
   |    |    | <_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewVS_7AnyView_: 0x10a9055f0; frame = (0 0; 393 852); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c10cf0>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600001712900; name = systemBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002128c0>>
   |    |    |    | <_TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$107f9077432PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV11iPhoneStudy11UIKitPeeker__: 0x10a90c550; baseClass = _UIConstraintBasedLayoutHostingView; frame = (0 374.333; 393 128.333); anchorPoint = (0, 0); tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0.478431 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000024ada0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_TtCV11iPhoneStudy11UIKitPeeker6MyView: 0x10a90bf60; frame = (0 0; 393 128.333); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000024ad40>>
```

We can see here that SwiftUI does all the drawing for the `VStack` and its subviews with just two instances of `UIView` subclasses (the ones whose names start with `_TtGC7SwiftUI`). It doesn't even turn the `Toggle` into a `UISwitch`.

Comment: Thanks for this Rob! Super helpful info in here. I was aware of UIViewRepresentable. And you are right, I was under the impression that each Swift view had a corresponding UIView under the hood. I was essentially trying to get access to _whatever_ the UIView looked like inside the context of a view modifier, and insert a CALayer with a gaussian blur at index 0. I can do something close with Representable and a ZStack, I think.

Comment: Really digging UIKitPeeker :)